# Changing BottomNavigationView single item icon and text color

Tags: android, kotlin, android-selector, android-bottomnavigationview

I have a BottomNavigationView:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        ...
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_menu_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_menu_color_selector"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

with **itemIconTint** and **itemTextColor** selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

and menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavFirst"
        android:icon="@drawable/bottom_nav_first_selector"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_first_title" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavSecond
        android:icon="@drawable/bottom_nav_second_selector"
        android:title="@string/bottom_nav_second_title" />

</menu>
```

and a selector for menu item icon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_nav_first_icon_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bottom_nav_first_icon_deselected" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Now depending on an application state I need to change one menu item icon color and title color. It should be grey when selected and deselected. I tried with methods **setTintList** or **setTint** with no success:

```
bottomNavView.menu.findItem(R.id.bottomNavFirst)?.icon?.setTintList(null)
bottomNavView.menu.findItem(R.id.bottomNavFirst)?.icon?.setTint(Color.GRAY)
```

Properties like **iconTintList** are not an option because my API level is 21. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

try this to change the title color:

```
    SpannableString titleSpannable = new  SpannableString("title");

    titleSpannable.setSpan(
            new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
            0,
            titleSpannable.length(),
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

bottomNavView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.bottomNavFirst).setTitle(titleSpannable);
```

I'm looking for how to change just one icon.

Comment: This changes the icon color for all menu items, I only want to change one.

Comment: @wwwww I edited my answer, but I still haven't found how to change just the color of an icon.